# breeze: error on lazy-loading

Tags: lazy-loading, breeze

With the following code:

```
$scope.mandat.entityAspect.loadNavigationProperty("OpenPositions")
 .fail(function(err){
  logger.error(err);
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

Error: The 'operator' parameter  must be an instance of the 'FilterQueryOp' enumeration, or it must be a 'string'

Whereas if I do:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("Mandates").where("Id", "==", mandatId)
           .expand("OpenPositions");

manager.executeQuery(query);
```

It works fine and the collection OpenPositions is loaded ok.

What am I doing wrong with the first method ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't repro this. There are several 'loadNavigationProperty' tests in the DocCode sample shipped in the Breeze zip.  Do these tests pass? If not, you are likely running an old version of Breeze?  If so, please send a small example of this failure to breeze@ideablade.com ( Attn: Jay Traband).

Comment: I haven't tried the tests yet, but what I can already tell you is that I'm using the very latest version of Breeze.

Comment: I've run the tests and they all passed.

Comment: Any chance you can send me a small repro?

Comment: right now, I don't think I can. I'd have to put the service online, which I can't. I'll try to dig a bit further

Comment: If you can repro with DocCode that would be fine.